# Is it possible to remove the "Shared" folder under Users?

Tags: macos, finder, sharing, user-account

Under "Sharing" in System Preferences, I do not have anything shared. However, I have a "Shared" folder under "Users". Is there a way to remove this folder?

[image: Shared Folder]

Comment: From time to time software will depend upon that folder existing. Is it causing you a problem worse than debugging future software issues?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's *possible*, but that doesn't mean you should do it.

Finder/etc doesn't stop you deleting it, and it's not a 'system' directory (despite being created by the system), but is it causing a problem, enough that you want to delete it? Apps can depend on that directory and deleting it could cause problems, now or in the future. I don't have any examples of such applications, but that's not to say they don't exist or may exist in the future.

Comment: It's also a fairly easy way to share data between users on the same computer--not necessarily sharing over a network. I agree, no good reason to delete.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow what George said, it's not going to cause any problems by just being there.

However, if it's bothering you simply being there then hide the folder using `chflags hidden /Users/Shared` in the terminal.

It will still exist, applications can still use it, and you won't see it anymore.

Comment: I tried this and got `chflags: /Users/Shared: Permission denied`

Comment: @rainbowsorbet run it using sudo, the folder is normally not flag writable by other users.